# Is there a way to filter or query unique results where unique is determined by one column but all columns are returned?

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

My data source range is A:AK (A6:AK1478).

The data is content (blogs, videos, etc) titles, authors, ratings, etc.(A:J) and values for how they map to categories (K:AK). 
A:J is text data.
K:AK is numerical data.

There are duplicate entries I cannot remove. The title of each piece of content is in column F; this is the only column I look at to determine duplicate values.

I want to query or filter (which is better?) all of this data into another sheet in order to obtain actual sums from columns K:AK. I want the formula to:

- Return all columns and rows from original data, AND
- *Disregard duplicates only in column F*

I do not want to delete duplicates from the original source. 
So far I have tried query and filter but no luck. I'm not an expert at advanced formulas, so any advice would be much appreciated!!

I'm very sorry also that I cannot share this spreadsheet as it is work-related. I'm happy to answer any questions I can though.

I have tried `=unique(query()` and `=unique(filter()` but this doesn't work because I can't figure out how to set column F as the range to look at for duplicates AND I want all columns returned, not just column F.

update: Here is a screenshot of my current query output

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot share this spreadsheet due to work restrictions :(

Comment: in that case pls create a dummy sheet with fake data matching your actual scenario

Comment: I added a screenshot above, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

try it like this - instead of `UNIQUE` use internal `QUERY` parameter `group by`:

```
=QUERY(DLEs!F6:AK1478, 
 "select F,sum(G),sum(H),sum(I),sum(J),sum(K),sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W),sum(X),sum(Y),sum(Z),sum(AA),sum(AB),sum(AC),sum(AD),sum(AE),sum(AF),sum(AG),sum(AH),sum(AI),sum(AJ),sum(AK) 
  where F is not null 
  group by F", 0)
```